# Chromium flash not playing on OpenSuse

Tags: opensuse, chrome, flash

Error

> You either have Javascript turned off or an old version of Flash Player.

I've tried several solutions on the internet.

- chrome://components/ lists nothing of interest
- Yast is unable to find `bunsen-pepperflash`
- Youtube works fine
- I'm running on a Dell XPS 15 2017 model.

Comment: Firefox still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and Chromium no longer fully support Flash by default, due to security concerns.

The announcement was already made some time ago:

[2016 - Google plans to start blocking Flash in Chrome this year](https://www.theverge.com/2016/5/15/11679394/chrome-to-block-flash-later-2016)

> Flash's death has been slow and painful, and now Google is planning to
>   deal it another blow. Google has detailed plans to start blocking most
>   Flash content with Chrome, with the change targeted toward the end of
>   this year.
>
> Under its current vision, nearly every website would have Flash
>   content blocked by default. Visitors would still be able to enable
>   Flash content on a site-by-site basis, but they would have to
>   specifically choose to do so. Chrome would display a prompt offering
>   to enable Flash; if chosen, Chrome would remember to run Flash on that
>   site for all future visits.
>
> THE TOP 10 SITES WITH FLASH WILL GET AN EXEMPTION
>
> Only 10 sites would have Flash enabled by default — the "top 10
>   domains using Flash," to avoid annoying people with too many prompts.
>   Those include YouTube, Facebook, Yahoo, Twitch, and Amazon. But
>   they'll only have a one year exemption. After that, it sounds like
>   they'll have Flash blocked by default, just like everyone else.

and from Google [blog](https://blog.google/products/chrome/flash-and-chrome/) Aug 2016:

> Today, more than 90% of Flash on the web loads behind the scenes to
>   support things like page analytics. This kind of Flash slows you down,
>   and starting this September,Chrome 53 will begin to block it. HTML5 is
>   much lighter and faster, and publishers are switching over to speed up
>   page loading and save you more battery life. You’ll see an improvement
>   in responsiveness and efficiency for many sites.
>
> This is similar to a change we made last September, when some Flash
>   content became click-to-play with Chrome 42. This had an immediate,
>   positive impact for our users by improving page load times and saving
>   battery power.

So I would say to Flash, so long, and good riddance.

If you still have legacy sites, or network enterprise equipment/VCenter devices that need Flash functionality, the path of least resistance is to open them with an alternative browser, like Firefox, where it seems more intuitive  to enable flash for the exception.

However, all the major browsers they are on the same page, so if internal developed sites, I would advise to upgrade them to a newer technology; if need be to keep access to legacy hardware, better keep a VM with and old version of a supported browser.

[Aug 2016 - Firefox is latest browser to kill off Adobe Flash support](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2465543/mozilla-firefox-is-latest-browser-to-kill-off-adobe-flash-support)

> Meanwhile, Firefox is beginning the process with a curated blacklist
>   of sites that can work without the Flash plug-in, expanding to become
>   a 'click to run' model for all content during next year.
>
> Mozilla has already confirmed that, like Google, it will abandon
>   support for all NPAPI (Netscape) plug-ins other than Flash from March
>   2017. This effectively kills Silverlight and Java too, although an extended support release will be available until 2018 for those
>   needing a little longer.
>
> The need to kill off Adobe Flash has long been recognised. The player
>   required 78 patches in December 2015 alone to cover security bugs in
>   the code.

Unfortunately, I am no longer using SuSE, would say to check this page as soon it goes out of maintenance mode https://software.opensuse.org/package/chromium-pepper-flash , because I suspect the package may be discontinued too.

Comment: FWIW, I ended up switching to elementary os.  Same problem.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey OS/X, FreeBSD same thing.